# How to write a string at the beginning of txt files massively?

Tags: php

I have 100 txt files on my webserver. I have to insert a string e.g. abcdef on the beginning of all of them using php and save them back again. How is this possible ?

Comment: Yeah, right. This does not have to do something with writing a trojan that infects all php files on a server, does it?

Comment: @Daniel It's just for the fun of it!

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps they're inserting a copyright notice into a bunch of plain text files?

Comment: I have 100 forms that I forgot to add a <h3>Search</h3> at the top of them

Comment: Sorry. I just had to remove the first line of nearly all my php files...

Comment: flat files are last decade, you want a db and a few scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [opendir](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [glob](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), [fopen](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), and [fwrite](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).  For example:

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $file) {
   $fh = fopen($file, 'c'); //Open file for writing, place pointer at start of file.
   fwrite($fh, 'abcdef');
   fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Hi, with an if statement I placed what I wanted at the begining but I can;t do the same to the end of the file ?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `fopen`.  It has many options.  'a' puts the pointer at the end of the file.  You can also use `fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END)` to move the end of the file, but it would be silly to do this when you can use the 'a' option.

Comment: I can't get it working. I placed it in a new file in the same folder with the files I want to change

Comment: I got it working but it replaced all of the contents with the string.

Comment: @mgutt, please do not change the code in answers, unless the person has given you permission to do so. If you feel something needs to be improved in example code, then make a suggestion in the comment, but if they choose to not make the change it is their choice. It is OK to improve grammar to make something more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, google found [this](http://mgccl.com/2007/07/01/prepend-string-to-a-file-with-stream).

```
function prepend($string, $filename) {
    $context = stream_context_create();
    $tmpname = tempnam(".");

    $fp = fopen($filename, "r", 1, $context);
    file_put_contents($tmpname, $string);
    file_put_contents($tmpname, $fp, FILE_APPEND);
    fclose($fp);

    unlink($filename);
    rename($tmpname, $filename);
}
```

So you call `prepend($string, $filename)` for every file and you're done.

Comment: My files start from 47 and end to 103.php . With an if statement I placed what I wanted at the begining but I can;t do the same to the end of the file. How can I modify the code for this ?

Comment: @Punkis: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: Is there a more automatic way like tandu's below that gets all the files of the folder?

Comment: Punkis: Write it yourself, it's not that hard, and it's out of the scope of this question.